# How to link 3 different U1accounts and sync them on all computers

Tags: windows, sync, share

We are 3 sisters living in 3 different locations (2 windows and 1 Mac).
Each of us has her own U1 account with photos to share.

Now we would like to have the content of each account locally synced on each sister's computer.

This would mean that me, sister A, I have my own U1account synced on my PC.
How to do to get the content of my 2 sisters accounts also locally on my computer, and automatically synced when they do some changes (add new photos for example)?

Thanks in advance.

Charlotte

Comment: Have **One** account and  use other System as different devices, would be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Share all your u1 contents with other sister's accounts. Other sisters, in their turn, should share all their contents toward you. 
There is a "share" entry in the Ubuntu One right-click menu of every file (on ubuntu). Otherwise you should use the web interface, I guess (never used U1 on win or mac).

Your sister's files should appear under your "Shared with Me" folder, and your content will show up in their "Shared with Me" folders on sister's pc.